# How many gems do I lose when I die?

Tags: lucky-luna

Whenever I die in Lucky Luna I lose some of my gems. The amount of gems I lose seems to vary. What determines how many gems I lose when I die?

[image: losing 230 gems]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You lose around 25% of your gems rounded down to a multiple of 10 when you die. The amount is capped to a maximum of 1000.**

I created a spreadsheet to record how many gems I lost each time I died. I found that the amount *usually* matched around 25% of my gems rounded down to a multiple of 10. As exceptions, the gems lost were rounded up if I had less than 80 gems and the gem loss was capped at 1000 gems.

[image: Spreadsheet of gems lost]